# Rails SimpleForm arithmetic calculation on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

For my first Rails project, I'm trying to create a form with the SimpleForm gem. The form has questions in radio button format and each answer has a score associated with it (1 - 4). My aim is to have the form add up the scores from each question (:vision_problems, :balance_issues, :nausea) and save the total score into a separate column (:total) once the user submits the form. What is the best way to approach this issue?

Currently, I'm using the following to display the total in my Show view, but having a :total column would be much better:

```
<%= @total = @symptom.nausea + @symptom.balance_issues + @symptom.vision_problems %>
```

Thank you for any help.

The form partial in Views:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@symptom) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.input :vision_problems, label_html: { class: "buttonhead" }, collection: [ 1 , 2, 3,      
4 ], as: :radio_buttons %>
<%= f.input :balance_issues, label_html: { class: "buttonhead" }, collection: [ 1 , 2, 3,  
4 ], as: :radio_buttons %>
<%= f.input :nausea, label_html: { class: "label label-info" }, collection: [ 1 , 2,  3,    
4 ], as: :radio_buttons %>
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The Symptom Model:

```
class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :description, :vision_problems, :balance_issues, :nausea, :user_id, :total

belongs_to :user

validates :user_id, presence: true 
end
```

The create part of the Symptom controller:

```
def create
@symptom = current_user.Symptoms.new(params[:symptom])

respond_to do |format|
  if @symptom.save
    format.html { redirect_to @symptom, notice: 'Symptom was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @symptom, status: :created, location: @symptom }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @symptom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct solution (if I understand what you're asking for) would be to set the `total` attribute in the controller's `create` method before saving it; i.e., adding the line

```
@symptom.total = @symptom.nausea + @symptom.balance_issues + 
                 @symptom.vision_problems
```

But I get the impression that what you really need is either a method or a *virtual attribute* (i.e., an attribute that's fetched and set through methods you define yourself as opposed to being mapped to a database column). Instead of creating a table column named `total`, you might define it as a model method:

```
class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :vision_problems, :balance_issues, 
                  :nausea, :user_id
  def total
    nausea + balance_issues + vision_problems
  end
end
```

Then, when you use `@symptom.total`, you're adding up the other attributes on the fly. The downside is that you can't manipulate the value of total directly (e.g., you can't say `@symptom.total += 1`) but that's something you may never want to do (or perhaps even actively prevent).

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I ended up using the latter of your two solutions- the model method. It solves my issue and does update the :total column as well. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback to generate the total when the object is saved.

Add a total column as usual

```
add_column :symptoms, :total, :integer
```

Add a callback to the Symptom model:

```
before_validation :update_total

def update_total
  total = nausea + balance_issues + vision_problems
end
```

There are a few options to choose from when deciding where in the callback chain you want this to occur.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I couldn't get it to work at first because I hadn't removed :total from the attr_accessible, but your solution does work once I used it correctly. In the meantime, I ended up using Mark's solution. Thank you for your time.